# Selecting columns from pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, hierarchical

I have DataFrame with MultiIndex columns that looks like this:

```
# sample data
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)
data
```

[image: sample data]

What is the proper, simple way of selecting only specific columns (e.g. `['a', 'c']`, not a range) from the second level?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
import itertools
tuples = [i for i in itertools.product(['one', 'two'], ['a', 'c'])]
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
print(new_index)
data.reindex_axis(new_index, axis=1)
```

[image: expected result]

It doesn't feel like a good solution, however, because I have to bust out `itertools`, build another MultiIndex by hand and then reindex (and my actual code is even messier, since the column lists aren't so simple to fetch). I am pretty sure there has to be some `ix` or `xs` way of doing this, but everything I tried resulted in errors.

Comment: Have you tried using dictionaries?

Comment: Not, I haven't. You mean to more quickly construct the MultiIndex? If so, that's not the point - I would like to avoid it and index directly with something like `data.xs(['a', 'c'], axis=1, level=1)`

Comment: Is there a reason you have that level as the second and not the first level?

Comment: It's more intuitive to me visually for the kind of data I have. Also, I wanted to learn how to do it generically - for an arbitrary level.

Comment: In later versions of pandas, you can use `loc` along with the `pd.IndexSlice` API which is now the preferred way of slicing MultIndexs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337009/4909087), and [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels/53927461#53927461)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's not great, but maybe:

```
>>> data
        one                           two                    
          a         b         c         a         b         c
0 -0.927134 -1.204302  0.711426  0.854065 -0.608661  1.140052
1 -0.690745  0.517359 -0.631856  0.178464 -0.312543 -0.418541
2  1.086432  0.194193  0.808235 -0.418109  1.055057  1.886883
3 -0.373822 -0.012812  1.329105  1.774723 -2.229428 -0.617690
>>> data.loc[:,data.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({"a", "c"})]
        one                 two          
          a         c         a         c
0 -0.927134  0.711426  0.854065  1.140052
1 -0.690745 -0.631856  0.178464 -0.418541
2  1.086432  0.808235 -0.418109  1.886883
3 -0.373822  1.329105  1.774723 -0.617690
```

would work?

Comment: Actually I think this is the optimal way of filtering out a list of labels in an arbitrary level of MultiIndex without creating all the tuples. I would just use `loc` for clarity.

Comment: To preserve the order of columns, it is better to use `isin(["a", "b"])`.

Comment: @Peaceful: what?  That doesn't change anything.  The result of the isin call is a bool Series, and its order is determined by the order of the original Series, not the argument to isin.

Comment: I tried it. And because `{"a", "b"}` is dictionary, it gave me columns ordered as `{"b", "a"}`. Of course I had different column names. What is going on?

Comment: `{"a", "b"}` is a set, not a dictionary, and that has nothing to do with how isin works.  If you have a question about how pandas is behaving, please open a new question instead of commenting on a four-year-old answer.

Comment: I meant set only. Sorry for that. But I do get that behavior. And using list instead of set solves the issue. I only casually asked what was going on. It is allowed to comment I guess.

Comment: @Peaceful: no, you don't.  Not with `isin` -- that's not how it works.  `x.isin(["a","b"])` is the same as `x.isin(["b","a","a"])` is the same as `x.isin({"a", "b"})`.  Again, please open a new question if you have a question about how pandas works, so that the answer can be useful to other people.

Comment: Note: `DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing`
The search continues...

Comment: @Evan I've updated the answer to use .loc to account for the deprecation. I think the solution based on `pd.IndexSlice` suggested by Nick P is more in pandas spirit, though.

Comment: This is a saviour

Comment: To select all the elements NOT in the list: data.loc[:,~data.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({"a", "c"})]

Answer (score 49):

The most straightforward way is with `.loc`:

```
>>> data.loc[:, (['one', 'two'], ['a', 'b'])]


   one       two     
     a    b    a    b
0  0.4 -0.6 -0.7  0.9
1  0.1  0.4  0.5 -0.3
2  0.7 -1.6  0.7 -0.8
3 -0.9  2.6  1.9  0.6
```

Remember that `[]` and `()` have special meaning when dealing with a `MultiIndex` object:

> (...) a tuple is interpreted as one **multi-level** key
>
> (...) a list is used to specify several keys [on the **same level**]
>
> (...) a tuple of lists refer to several values within a level

When we write `(['one', 'two'], ['a', 'b'])`, the first list inside the tuple specifies all the values we want from the 1st level of the `MultiIndex`. The second list inside the tuple specifies all the values we want from the 2nd level of the `MultiIndex`.

**Edit 1:** Another possibility is to use `slice(None)` to specify that we want anything from the first level (works similarly to slicing with `:` in lists). And then specify which columns from the second level we want.

```
>>> data.loc[:, (slice(None), ["a", "b"])]

   one       two     
     a    b    a    b
0  0.4 -0.6 -0.7  0.9
1  0.1  0.4  0.5 -0.3
2  0.7 -1.6  0.7 -0.8
3 -0.9  2.6  1.9  0.6
```

If the syntax `slice(None)` does appeal to you, then another possibility is to use `pd.IndexSlice`, which helps slicing frames with more elaborate indices.

```
>>> data.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ["a", "b"]]]

   one       two     
     a    b    a    b
0  0.4 -0.6 -0.7  0.9
1  0.1  0.4  0.5 -0.3
2  0.7 -1.6  0.7 -0.8
3 -0.9  2.6  1.9  0.6
```

When using `pd.IndexSlice`, we can use `:` as usual to slice the frame.

Source: [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index), [How to use `slice(None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Comment: note that the column name of the resulting DataFrame is `a b a b` and not `a c a c`.

Comment: @SilvanMühlemann I fixed, please take a look and let me know if there are other issues! Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is the most intuitive way.

Answer (score 20):

You can use either, `loc` or `ix` I'll show an example with `loc`:

```
data.loc[:, [('one', 'a'), ('one', 'c'), ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'c')]]
```

When you have a MultiIndexed DataFrame, and you want to filter out only some of the columns, you have to pass a list of tuples that match those columns. So the itertools approach was pretty much OK, but you don't have to create a new MultiIndex:

```
data.loc[:, list(itertools.product(['one', 'two'], ['a', 'c']))]
```

Comment: And even `.loc` and similar are not necessary. `data[[('one', 'a'), ('one', 'c'), ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'c')]]` works as well. Tested on 0.23.4.

Answer (score 18):

## `ix` and `select` are deprecated!

The use of `pd.IndexSlice` makes `loc` a more preferable option to `ix` and `select`.

---

### **[`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)**

```
# Setup
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.DataFrame('x', index=range(4), columns=col)
data

  one       two      
    a  b  c   a  b  c
0   x  x  x   x  x  x
1   x  x  x   x  x  x
2   x  x  x   x  x  x
3   x  x  x   x  x  x
```

```
data.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['a', 'c']]]

  one    two   
    a  c   a  c
0   x  x   x  x
1   x  x   x  x
2   x  x   x  x
3   x  x   x  x
```

You can alternatively an `axis` parameter to `loc` to make it explicit which axis you're indexing from:

```
data.loc(axis=1)[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['a', 'c']]]

  one    two   
    a  c   a  c
0   x  x   x  x
1   x  x   x  x
2   x  x   x  x
3   x  x   x  x
```

---

### **[`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html)**

Calling `data.columns.get_level_values` to filter with `loc` is another option:

```
data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['a', 'c'])]

  one    two   
    a  c   a  c
0   x  x   x  x
1   x  x   x  x
2   x  x   x  x
3   x  x   x  x
```

This can naturally allow for filtering on any conditional expression on a single level. Here's a random example with lexicographical filtering:

```
data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1) > 'b']

  one two
    c   c
0   x   x
1   x   x
2   x   x
3   x   x
```

---

More information on slicing and filtering MultiIndexes can be found at [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels/53927461#53927461).

Comment: Both approaches work for me, but the latter seems to be faster. I observed `pd.IndexSlice` three times as long (at least with my dataset, which has a two level column multiindex and a shape of `(3610, 30)`). --> `pd.IndexSlice` with `670 µs ± 4.49 µs per loop` and `data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['a', 'b', 'c'])]` with `215 µs ± 3.05 µs per loop`

Comment: also: `pd.IndexSlice` does not preserve the order of the columns in my case (`pandas==1.2.4`), the second does.

Answer (score 17):

I think there is a much better way (now), which is why I bother pulling this question (which was the top google result) out of the shadows:

```
data.select(lambda x: x[1] in ['a', 'b'], axis=1)
```

gives your expected output in a quick and clean one-liner:

```
        one                 two          
          a         b         a         b
0 -0.341326  0.374504  0.534559  0.429019
1  0.272518  0.116542 -0.085850 -0.330562
2  1.982431 -0.420668 -0.444052  1.049747
3  0.162984 -0.898307  1.762208 -0.101360
```

It is mostly self-explaining, the `[1]` refers to the level.

Comment: Note: `FutureWarning: 'select' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You can use .loc[labels.map(crit)] as a replacement.`

Answer (score 11):

To select all columns named `'a'` and `'c'` at the second level of your column indexer, you can use slicers:

```
>>> data.loc[:, (slice(None), ('a', 'c'))]

        one                 two          
          a         c         a         c
0 -0.983172 -2.495022 -0.967064  0.124740
1  0.282661 -0.729463 -0.864767  1.716009
2  0.942445  1.276769 -0.595756 -0.973924
3  2.182908 -0.267660  0.281916 -0.587835
```

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) you can read more about slicers.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly easier, to my mind, riff on [Marc P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656640/marc-p)'s [answer using slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872784/3329384):

```
import pandas as pd
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)

data.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['a', 'c']]]

        one                 two          
          a         c         a         c
0 -1.731008  0.718260 -1.088025 -1.489936
1 -0.681189  1.055909  1.825839  0.149438
2 -1.674623  0.769062  1.857317  0.756074
3  0.408313  1.291998  0.833145 -0.471879
```

As of pandas 0.21 or so, [.select is deprecated in favour of .loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#series-select-and-dataframe-select).

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.loc(axis="columns")` (or `df.loc(axis=1)` to access just the columns and slice away:

```
df.loc(axis="columns")[:, ["a", "c"]]
```

Comment: Or equivalently if you're going for brevity, `axis=1`. This is by far the most visually appealing (and probably most concise) solution imho.

Comment: for sure :) my brain is slow and forgetful sometimes, so i tend to do the human readable thing lol

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), where you can use a dictionary to select -  the key of the dictionary is the level (either a number or label), and the value is the label(s) to be selected:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
data.select_columns({1:['a','c']})

        one                 two          
          a         c         a         c
0 -0.089182 -0.523464 -0.494476  0.281698
1  0.968430 -1.900191 -0.207842 -0.623020
2  0.087030 -0.093328 -0.861414 -0.021726
3 -0.952484 -1.149399  0.035582  0.922857
```

Answer (score 1):

### For arbitrary level of the column value

If the level of the column index shall be arbitrary, this might help you a bit:

```
class DataFrameMultiColumn(pd.DataFrame) :
    def loc_multicolumn(self, keys):
        depth = lambda L: isinstance(L, list) and max(map(depth, L))+1
        
        result = []
        col = self.columns
        
        # if depth of keys is 1, all keys need to be true
        if depth(keys) == 1:
            for c in col:
                # select all columns which contain all keys
                if set(keys).issubset(set(c)) : 
                    result.append(c)
        # depth of 2 indicates, 
        # the product of all sublists will be formed
        elif depth(keys) == 2 :
            keys = list(itertools.product(*keys)) 
            for c in col:
                for k in keys :
                    # select all columns which contain all keys
                    if set(k).issubset(set(c)) : 
                        result.append(c)
                        
        else :
            raise ValueError("Depth of the keys list exceeds 2")

        # return with .loc command
        return self.loc[:,result]
```

`.loc_multicolumn` will return the same as calling `.loc` but without specifing the level for each key.
Please note that this might be a problem is values are the same in multiple column levels!

### Example :

#### Sample data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
    col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (4,6)), columns=col)
    data_mc = DataFrameMultiColumn(data)

>>> data_mc
      one       two      
        a  b  c   a  b  c
    0   5  8  9   5  0  0
    1   1  7  6   9  2  4
    2   5  2  4   2  4  7
    3   7  9  1   7  0  6
```

#### Cases:

List depth 1 requires all elements in the list be fit.

```
>>> data_mc.loc_multicolumn(['a', 'one'])
  one
    a
0   5
1   1
2   5
3   7
>>> data_mc.loc_multicolumn(['a', 'b'])

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []

Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> data_mc.loc_multicolumn(['one','a', 'b'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

List depth 2 allows all elements of the Cartesian product of keys list.

```
>>> data_mc.loc_multicolumn([['a', 'b']])
  one    two   
    a  b   a  b
0   5  8   5  0
1   1  7   9  2
2   5  2   2  4
3   7  9   7  0
    
>>> data_mc.loc_multicolumn([['one'],['a', 'b']])
  one   
    a  b
0   5  8
1   1  7
2   5  2
3   7  9
```

For the last:
All combination from `list(itertools.product(["one"], ['a', 'b']))` are given if all elements in the combination fits.

Answer (score 0):

The .loc[:, list of column tuples] approach given in one of the earlier answers fails in case the multi-index has boolean values, as in the example below:

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[False, False, True,  True],
                                 [False, True,  False, True]])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=col)
data.loc[:,[(False, True),(True, False)]]
```

This fails with a `ValueError: PandasArray must be 1-dimensional.`

Compare this to the following example, where the index values are strings and not boolean:

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["False", "False", "True",  "True"],
                                 ["False", "True",  "False", "True"]])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=col)
data.loc[:,[("False", "True"),("True", "False")]]
```

This works fine.

You can transform the first (boolean) scenario to the second (string) scenario with

```
data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(str(i),str(j)) for i,j in data.columns],
    names=data.columns.names)
```

and then access with string instead of boolean column index values (the `names=data.columns.names` parameter is optional and not relevant to this example). This example has a two-level column index, if you have more levels adjust this code correspondingly.

Getting a boolean multi-level column index arises, for example, if one does a crosstab where the columns result from two or more comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers are here depending on what is the exact output that you need.

If you want to get a one leveled dataframe from your selection (which can be sometimes really useful) simply use :

```
df.xs('theColumnYouNeed', level=1, axis=1)
```

If you want to keep the multiindex form (similar to metakermit's answer) :

```
data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1) == "columnName"]
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

#### Rename columns before selecting

- Sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)
data
```

- rename columns

```
data.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in data.columns]
data
```

- Subset column

```
data['one_a']
```