# Pandas select specific lower-level columns in MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I don't know if the question has been answered again, but I haven't found anything similar

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame with two level columns, for example:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar','bar', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two','three'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 9), columns=arrays)
print(df)

        bar                           foo                           qux  \
        one       two     three       one       two     three       one   
0  1.255724 -0.692387 -1.485324  2.265736  0.494645  1.973369 -0.326260   
1 -0.903874  0.695460 -0.950076  0.181590 -2.345611  1.288061  0.980166   
2 -0.294882  1.034745  1.423288 -0.895625 -0.847338  0.470444  0.373579   


        two     three  
0  0.136427 -0.136479  
1  0.702732 -1.894376  
2  0.506240 -0.456519
```

I want to select specific columns from the second level for every first level column independently.

For example, i want to get as result something like this:

```
        bar                 foo       qux          
        one       two       two       one     three
0  1.255724 -0.692387  0.494645 -0.326260 -0.136479
1 -0.903874  0.695460 -2.345611  0.980166 -1.894376
2 -0.294882  1.034745 -0.847338  0.373579 -0.456519
```

I have seen this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470323/selecting-columns-from-pandas-multiindex) but it isn't what i want to achieve.

Now I am doing it like this:

```
level0 = ['bar','foo','qux']
level1 = [['one','two'],['two'],['one','three']]

df_list=[]
for i,value in enumerate(level0):
    df_list.append(df.loc[:,(value,level1[i])])
new_df = pd.concat([i for i in df_list],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

But it doesn't seem to me as the best solution.

Is there any better (more "pandas") approach to solve this?

Comment: `df.loc[:, [(l0, l1) for l0, l1_ in zip(level0, level1) for l1 in l1_]]` ?

Comment: `df.loc[:, [(l0,l1) for x,y in zip(level0,level1) for l0, l1 in product([x], y)]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the data, you can pick out the columns first, and use column extraction;

```
cols = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'level_0':x, 'level_1':y}) 
                  for x,y in zip(level0,level1)]
                ).values

df[cols]
```

Output:

```
        bar                 foo       qux          
        one       two       two       one     three
0  0.729061 -0.876547  0.312557  0.736568  0.250469
1  0.619194  0.451023  0.803252 -1.636403 -0.854607
2  0.254690 -1.054859 -1.223274  0.398411 -1.448396
```