# Add multiple columns at once to multiindex Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe multiindex pandas dataframe `df`

```
First    Foo     Bar
Second   Begin   Begin
1        5       1
2        4       4
3        6       6
```

And I want to add two columns of the same name

```
First    Foo             Bar
Second   Begin   End     Begin   End
1        5       1       1       2       
2        4       5       4       4       
3        6       7       6       7
```

From this source (`new`):

```
First    Foo    Bar
1        1      2
2        5      4
3        7      7
```

I tried things like `df[:] = new[:]` but this returned only NaN

An alternative would be to use something like a for-loop but that's not the Pandas approach. Searching the web did not give me any insights as to solving this problem.

How can I add new columns with the same name and shape to every first level of a multiindex Pandas dataframe?

Edit:

This approach `df[('Foo', 'End')] = new['Foo'] df[('Bar', 'End')] = new['Bar']` is not an option because in my actual problem there is not two columns to be added, but hundreds of columns.

Comment: why are you using a multi-index?  There may be an easier way to achieve what you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting columns from pandas MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470323/selecting-columns-from-pandas-multiindex)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney no my question is not about selecting but about inserting columns

Comment: @anon01 and that easier way is?

Comment: use columns in place of a multi-index

Comment: Does the update resolve your question?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes, but I don't believe this is the 'Pandian' way. Using for loops breaks the logic of Pandas.

Comment: Your trying to get data from one dateframe to a different dataframe, which isn't the same as performing in dataframe calculations with a loop.

Comment: I was hoping there was a pretty solution to this, but it is always possible that there isn't. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it answers the question, please accept the answer. If an answer you like better comes along. you can unaccept an answer and accept a new answer. Have a nice day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Multi-column names are passed as `Tuples`, like `df[('Foo', 'End')]`.

```py
import pamadas as pd

# test data
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Foo', 'Bar'], ['Begin', 'Begin']], names=['First', 'Second'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 1], [4, 4], [6, 6]], columns=col)
new = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [1, 5, 7], 'Bar': [2, 4, 7]})

# write new columns
df[('Foo', 'End')] = new['Foo']
df[('Bar', 'End')] = new['Bar']

# display(df)
First    Foo   Bar Foo Bar
Second Begin Begin End End
0          5     1   1   2
1          4     4   5   4
2          6     6   7   7
```

### For many columns

- `col`, column name in `new`, must correspond to the top level column name in `df`.

```py
for col in new.columns:
    df[(col, 'new col name')] = new[col]
```