# How can I subset this pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

[image: This is the head of my dataframe]

I am trying to understand how I can certain column of NFLX, and generally how the data frame is actually constructed. Are NFLX, AAPL, GOOG, etc. groupings, or are they labels for certain columns/rows?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me.

This is a pandas data frame, using following code to create:
data = yf.download(['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'NFLX', 'ACLS', 'TSLA'], start=start, end=end, group_by ='ticker')

Comment: You have a multindex dataframe. Refer to his: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: The acquired data frame consists of multiple columns. Try the following to understand the structure. `data.columns` OUTPUT: `MultiIndex([('ACLS',      'Open'),
            ('ACLS',      'High'),
            ('ACLS',       'Low'), ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting columns from pandas MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470323/selecting-columns-from-pandas-multiindex)